# Effect of Temperature on Chemical Reaction Equilibrium

Tags: reaction-mechanism, thermodynamics, equilibrium

here is the question (part I):
[image: Chemical equilibrium of Deacon's process]

For part (i), I need some assistance, I cannot figure out how to do the question. I know eventually what to do, it's just working out the equilibrium constants I'm having trouble with. So to start, I want to work out the K values at $\pu{600K}$ and $\pu{800K}$; I do this by considering the total pressure:

$$
\text{Total Pressure} = 1 \text{ bar}
$$

Initially:

$$
P_\ce{O2} + P_\ce{HCl} = \pu{1bar}
$$
Since there are $4$ moles of $\ce{HCl}$ per $\ce{O2}$ we can write:

$$
5P_\ce{O2} = \pu{1bar}  \to P_{\ce{O2}} = \pu{0.2bar}
$$

$85\%$ conversion means that in the end, $85\%$ of the oxygen has reacted; therefore, there is $\pu{0.2bar}*0.15 = \pu{0.03bar}$ oxygen remaining, therefore $\pu{0.12bar}~\ce{HCl}$ remaining. In addition to this, each mole of oxygen reacted results in $4$ new moles being created, and therefore there are $(0.85*0.2*2)\,\mathrm{bar}$ of water (and also chlorine) produced. With this information, I can calculate my equilibrium constant, right?

Comment: What is the equation for determining the temperature dependence of the equilibrium constant for a reaction?

Comment: @ChesterMiller -G = RTlnK?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Basically, I know if I assume the enthalpy of reaction is constant I can write: $ln\frac{K}{K_1} = \frac{\Delta H^o_T}{R} - (\frac{1}{T}- \frac{1}{T_1})$, so I can find the enthalpy of reaction. But I do not feel my method is right for getting the K values, does the total pressure have to remain constant at 1 bar? To me that does not make sense

Comment: No.  The total pressure does not have to remain constant at 1 bar.  What you need to do is review the derivation of the equilibrium constant from $\Delta G^0$

Comment: @ChesterMiller Hmm, I know you start at dG = -sdT + vdP + sum(chemical potentials), and I know the subsequent steps, I don't see how it can help though :/

Comment: Are you familiar with $\Delta G=\Delta G^0+RT\ln{Q}$?

Comment: @ChesterMiller Yes sir, and at equilibrium , $\Delta G = 0 \implies - \Delta G^o_T = RTlnK$

Comment: So, when you use the equation $K=\exp({-\Delta G^0/RT})$, does the total pressure have to be 1 bar?

Comment: No, there are no restrictions, @ChesterMiller

Comment: Then I can't understand why you feel that you cannot use the equation involving $\Delta H^0$ to determine the value of K at 600K.

Comment: @ChesterMiller My confusion stems from the question not specifying whether the pressure is maintained at 1 bar or not, if it is then my above working is wrong as the total pressures do not add up to 1 but if the pressure is not constant then my working works, I'm just confused with the system really.

Comment: This all goes back to the definition of $\Delta G^0$.  Please state your understanding of $\Delta G^0$

Comment: @ChesterMiller Ok, so if we consider the reaction, A + B --> C, then: $\Delta G^o = \mu^0_{C} - \mu^0_{B} - \mu^0_{A}$, basically the difference in chemical potential for the pure components at T.

Comment: You omitted that the pressure of each pure component is 1 bar.  So, in state 1, you have pure reactants (in separate containers) at temperature T and 1 bar.  And, in state 2, you have pure products (in separate containers) at temperature T and 1 bar.  Now, if you change the temperature, holding the pressure of each component constant at 1 bar, you have for each component $dG_A=S_AdT$

Comment: @ChesterMiller Right, so the equilibrium constant is independent of pressure,  so whatever K I get it should be independent of the total pressure in the system, be it 1 bar or something else. But when I am working out K by considering that K = $\frac{P_c}{P_aP_b}$ where those are the partial pressures, suppose I start with 0.2 bar partial pressure of A, if 85% reacts, is the final partial pressure of A 0.2*0.15, even if the pressure of the system changes?

Comment: ah okay, I get is now @ChesterMiller, thank you for your help. Changing the pressure doesn't affect the equilibrium constant but it does have an affect on the position of equilibrium. In my case, all I need to do is set up the question in terms of extent of reaction (which I know is 0.85), the pressure is 1 bar for the reaction, with this information I can calculate the equilibrium constant. Then do what I said earlier. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nicely analyzed!!!!